# Is there a safe way to softly shutdown iMac via start-button?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, imac, shutdown

I use my iMac 2011 in Target Display Mode under High Sierra, to use it as an external display for my M1 MacBook Air from 2020. (works well, [despite Apple websites](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) say newer than 2019 is not supported).

It has no keyboard, no mouse, and no internet connection - WIFI and BT turned off.

On the iMac, I created a user that automagically logs in to MacOs. When I plug in DisplayPort cable to the laptop via a mDP 1.4 adapter, the Mac [automatically](https://www.lifewire.com/use-imac-as-monitor-with-target-display-mode-2260906) switches into Target Display Mode. See picture for my DisplayPort adapter.

What I would like is a way to shut down the iMac nicely, not a hard stop by holding the start button for N seconds.

For example, on my Linux NUC, I can shut down smoothly by hitting the on/off button twice in a second.

Can this be done on macOS (especially High Sierra) too?

[image: macbook adapter and DP cable]

Comment: There's no "despite".  iMac up to 2014 support TDM, you have a 2011.  The year of the laptop is irrelevant.

Comment: How do you enter Target Display Mode? I thought you have to press Command-F2 on the keyboard of the iMac and you say the iMac does not have a keyboard.

Comment: @MarcWilson There is a despite, since that is what Apple websites states: "The other Mac that you're connecting it to must have been introduced in 2019 or earlier and have macOS Catalina or earlier installed."

Comment: @DavidAnderson: good question. Thanks. I added info in the description above, and a photo, in case it is of help to others.

Comment: I have a 2011 iMac in TDM which is connected to a 2013 iMac by a [Thunderbolt cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD862LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-05-m). I wrote a script called `Shut Down` that can be accessed from [the menu bar of the 2013 iMac](https://imgur.com/a/tuEbJcC). This script will shut down the 2011 iMac when selected. This is done by using `ssh`. For this to work in your case, you would have to allow an internet connection between your iMac and your MacBook Air.

Comment: IMO, I think you may be better off by leaving the TDM reference out of your question and just focus on how to turn the iMac off by pressing the power button.